# Mocha test not reaching 2nd Express callback and returning to 1st

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I need help in the below code. I am testing a service which is sending request to a particular endpoint and I need to capture the body of the request, (using node express for this). The runner is mocha tests and has more than 1 it block.
When I am debugging the test, first it block works as expected (assertion passes), but when the control reaches second it block ,once the request is posted, the control is back to the first block again and the assertion in second block is never reached. What am I doing wrong here?

```
{
    var express = require("express");
    var bodyPaser = require('body-parser');
    var expressObj = new express();
    expressObj.use(bodyPaser.json());

    describe('describe', function () {
        before('describe', function () {
            expressObj.listen(8080);
        });

        it('first It', function (done) {
            expressObj.post('/mytest/first', function (req, res) {
                res.send("Hello");
                //  assert.equal(JSON.stringify(req.body), JSON.stringify('first":test'));
                done();
            });
        });

        it('second it', function (done) {
            expressObj.post('/mytest/first', function (req, res) {
                res.send("Hello");
                //  assert.equal(JSON.stringify(req.body), JSON.stringify('first":test'));
                done();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: have you considered to use 3rd party lib such as `supertest` or `chai-request`?

Answer (score 0):

The first and second tests are merely setting up the route, but you aren't actually sending a request to either of the routes you've described. So the tests begin, but the first one isn't actually doing anything, so done is never called, which is why the second test doesn't begin to run at all. To test these routes you'll need to create a request for each route after defining them. Here is a working demo of your code:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyPaser = require('body-parser');
var expressObj = new express();
expressObj.use(bodyPaser.json());
const request = require('request');

describe('describe', function () {
    before('describe', function (done) {
        expressObj.listen(8080, function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            done(err);
            return;
          }

          console.log('listening on localhost:8080');
          done();
        });
    });

    it('first It', function (done) {
        expressObj.post('/mytest/first', function (req, res) {
                        res.send("Hello");
            //  assert.equal(JSON.stringify(req.body), JSON.stringify('first":test'));
            done();
        });
        request.post('http://localhost:8080/mytest/first');
    });

    it('second it', function (done) {
        expressObj.post('/mytest/second', function (req, res) {
            res.send("Hello");
            //  assert.equal(JSON.stringify(req.body), JSON.stringify('first":test'));
            done();
        });

        request.post('http://localhost:8080/mytest/second');
    });
});
```

Comment: As i am testing a webservice, i am expecting a post request on the localhost and not sending a post request.

Comment: But the closing the server afterEach 'It' execution and starting it again beforeEach worked well for me.